# Magnolia defaultAction vs clicking the actual action from the action bar difference in getting JCR item

Tags: magnolia

In Magnolia, Is there a difference in getting the JCR Node of the related item (relatedItem.getJcrItem()) for the following 2 scenarios:

1. There's a defaultAction which is "Edit Item" that is defined for the actionbar. On double click of an item in the workbench list, a dialog will open to allow me to edit. Then I click "Cancel". Then I click the "Add Item" from the actionbar.
2. I click the item, then I click the "Edit Item", a dialog will open to allow me to edit. Then I click "Cancel". Then I click the "Add Item" from the actionbar.

I noticed that currently in the scenario 1, the JCR node will be the node of the item that I previously selected which shouldn't be the case. The  should be a new node, so the relatedItem.getJcrItem() for this case should be the parent node item where the new item will be added.

The scenario 2 shows a correct node when calling relatedItem.getJcrItem().

Because of this behavior, the scenario 1 will save the new item as a child node of the previously selected item.

I hope I explain this clearly. Anyone have any idea about this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the difference between two scenarios ? I mean both seemed to follow the same pattern with the same actions, doesn't it ?

Comment: @Ducaz035 the first scenario uses double click to edit the item. The second scenario uses the actions in the action bar to edit the item. Although yeah both is pointing to the same action. The problem is however, after cancelling the dialog in the scenario 1, when I try to add new item, the item is being saved as a child node of the previous item that I double click.  It should be the sibling of the previous item. Did you get what I mean?

Comment: Yes i got it now, thank you for the clarification. Perhaps the issue here is that selected item in the list somehow differ in two approaches. Can you please tell me which app are you using for those scenarios?

Comment: @Ducaz035 Actually I'm using a custom app, but you can also replicate this easily in the Security App, however you need to change the configuration for the security app by removing this node:  /modules/security-app/apps/security/subApps/users/actions/addUser/availability/nodeTypes.  By removing this node, it will allow you to "Add User" after clicking the cancel in the dialog.  So after applying the changes in the config, you can try to do the scenario 1 and you will see that the after you "Add user", the new user will be under the node of the user you previously double click. Thanks! :)

Comment: Okay then that explains the case, I will write an answer very soon with summarising what you might do, cheers.

Comment: @Ducaz035 Thank you very much :) ! My guess is that when you double click and cancel the dialog, it will still remember the root node to be the previously selected one. That's why the "Add User" in the security app doesn't work since the availability of the action is for folder node type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments above, Magnolia prevents those errors by adding availability rule for the add action due to the folder structure basically. It keeps your selection and thus add action shouldn't be available if a folder is not selected. If you wanna achieve such then you should create your own action and upon cancel you should be selecting the parent node of the given item.

Cheers,

Comment: @Ducaz0305 I don't think there's a onPostExecute method for OpenEditDialogAction which I'm using?  Ok, so since Magnolia uses this availability rule then it mean's that the scenario in the Security app where the user tries to double click the user node, then cancel the dialog that pops up, will result to user not able to click the "Add User" anymore, so this scenario is actually done in purpose by Magnolia, is my understanding correct? Although I find this behavior of not being able to "Add User" looks like a bug.

Comment: It is not a bug I'd say because you are selecting a user and your selection does not change, therefore it is not possible to add a user because your selection is indeed an user and you are required to select a folder to add a user below it. There is sort of a tree structure there with files(users) and folders. For the onPostExecute, i changing the answer because you are not using a command action and thus its not available.

Comment: I updated my answer and tried to give an idea of how to achieve it, but the behaviour seems to be correct and therefore expected.

Comment: ok thanks for you suggestion! :) For the behavior of Magnolia App, probably because the UI doesnt show that the item is selected (In fact the workbench will display "No item selected" and the "Add User" is enabled which is confusing and would look like a bug.  Anyways thanks! :)

Comment: For further improvement, I think Magnolia can avoid this confusion if upon double click of the item and click "Cancel", the selected item will be highlighted also in the workbench, just like the behavior when you manually click the edit action instead of double clicking. In this way, it will not be confusing for the user and also people will not do customization just to cater this part. :)

Comment: If you are interested, please feel free to create an issue in the issue repository, Magnolia is listening to its customers :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111447/discussion-between-jen-sze-and-ducaz035).

Comment: Can you please accept the answer, if you are happy with it ? ,thanks